# Title: "Getting 'PERMISSION_DENIED' error with status code 500 when calling 'video intelligence api’

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

I was implementing video intelligence api for one of my project.

Getting brown error:

message
:
"7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission"
stack
:
"

```
<span class="stack internal">at callErrorFromStatus (./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)\n<span class="stack internal">at Object.onReceiveStatus (./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)\n<span class="stack internal">at Object.onReceiveStatus (./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)\n<span class="stack internal">at Object.onReceiveStatus (./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)\n<span class="stack internal">at ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78\n<span class="stack internal">at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)\n<span class="stack internal">at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:34)\n<span class="stack internal">at ServiceClientImpl. (./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)\n<span class="stack internal">at ./node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/build/src/v1/video_intelligence_service_client.js:230:29\n<span class="stack internal">at ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16\n<span class="stack internal">at repeat (./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:80:25)\n<span class="stack internal">at ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:118:13\n<span class="stack internal">at LongrunningApiCaller._wrapOperation (./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longRunningCalls/longRunningApiCaller.js:55:16)\n<span class="stack internal">at ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longRunningCalls/longRunningApiCaller.js:46:25\n<span class="stack internal">at OngoingCallPromise.call (./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)\n<span class="stack internal">at LongrunningApiCaller.call (./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longRunningCalls/longRunningApiCaller.js:45:19)
```

"
statusCode
:
500
statusMessage
:
""
url
:
"/api/video"

I’m using video intelligence api version : 4.2.2

Comment: Can you share more about the context and the code?